# Binary search a left/right most element when there are duplicates

Tags: .net, algorithm, binary-search, .net-standard

How do you find leftmost or rightmost element using binary search in .NET when there are duplicates in an array? Yes, there is binary search but it is not handy if we have duplicates.

[`Array.BinarySearch()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netstandard-2.1#System_Array_BinarySearch_System_Array_System_Object_) returns the index of some element equal to the searched one, ie the first one it stumbles on if it there. From docs:

> Duplicate elements are allowed. If the Array contains more than one element equal to value, the method returns the index of only one of the occurrences, and not necessarily the first one.

Here is an example. We have an array, `1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3`. The method should always return leftmost occurrence, ie for 2 it returns 3, for 3 - 6, etc.

Handy implementation of it exists in Python, `bisect.bisect_left`, I wonder why notorious .NET does not have such one?

Yes, we can run binary search two times with e and e-1 but what if we have many adjacent duplicates like in the example above? Then one can just move to the left, but what if there are a lot of duplicates?

Comment: so you're assuming the array is sorted, right?

Comment: Sure, the array is sorted already.

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to do it (then you should probably talk about your own attempts)? Or why it isn't built-in? Or both?

Comment: Both. How would you do it in .NET (your code). If you would answer the second would be great

Answer (score 3):

```
    // Returns left-most index to insert element, ie. it can return 0 or array.Count() 
    public int BinarySearchLeft<T>(IList<T> array, T element) 
         where T : IComparable
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = array.Count();
        while (lo < hi)
        {
            int mid = (lo+hi) / 2;
            if (array[mid].CompareTo(element) < 0)
                lo = mid + 1;
            else
                hi = mid;
        }
        return lo;
    }
```

Comment: You are repeating the same problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why? It finds the leftmost because it discards the equal one.

Comment: Sorry , my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an auxiliary array to block traverse the item if it is traversed once! The idea is pretty simple --

1. once you found the key, mark it as traverse ( so that, if second time you get the same item you can recognize whether the same indexed-item is traverse or not, kind of dfs :) can use a boolean array for this. and keep on doing this, until you get an item which is not your "key";

   1.1 if you found the item, check the current index is lesser than or not compare to previously found index [for leftmost index] if so replace it with the current index.

   1.2 if you found the item, check the current index is greater than or not compare to previously found index [for right index] if so replace it with the current index.
2. use a regular binary search algorithm for the rest of the items.

Once you traverse the whole array return Pair of left and right most index.

Here, is the implementation of the above approach: [In Java]

```
public class LeftRightMostOcc {
static class Pair{
    int left, right;
    // initial value for left and right pair
    public void setLeftMostPair() {
        this.left = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    public void setRightMostPair() {
        this.right = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}

private static Pair binarySearchUtil(int [] a, int key, int low, int high, boolean [] visited, Pair obj) {
    if(high >= low) {
        int middle = low + ((high-low)/2);
        // found key, and not visited before
        if(a[middle] == key && !visited[middle]) {
            // update if less value you get, for left pair
            if(middle < obj.left)
                obj.left = middle;

            // update if right value you get, for right pair
            if(middle > obj.right)
                obj.right = middle;

            // mark the index
            visited[middle] = true;

            // keep on doing this, until you get an item which is not your "key"
            Pair flag = binarySearchUtil(a, key, low, middle-1, visited, obj);

            if(flag != null)
                flag = binarySearchUtil(a, key, middle+1, high, visited, obj);                  
        }
        // apply regular binary search algo for the rest of the item. 
        else if(a[middle] > key) {
            return binarySearchUtil(a, key, low, middle-1, visited, obj);
        }

        else {
            return binarySearchUtil(a, key, middle+1, high, visited, obj);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
private static Pair binarySearch(int [] a, int key, int low, int high) {
    boolean [] visited = new boolean[a.length];
    Pair object = new Pair();
    object.setLeftMostPair();
    object.setRightMostPair();
    return binarySearchUtil(a, key, low, high, visited, object);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a = {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5};

    Pair object = binarySearch(a, 2, 0, a.length-1);
    System.out.println("LeftMost Index: "+object.left+" - RightMost Index: "+object.right);
 }
}
```

O/P: LeftMost Index: 3 - RightMost Index: 6 [for key - 2]

O/P: LeftMost Index: 10 - RightMost Index: 10 [for key - 4]

O/P: LeftMost Index: 11 - RightMost Index: 14 [for key - 5]

Comment: So in one run it gets both leftmost and rightmost. Nice if it'd have been .NET/C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by supplying a modified key comparison function the returns greater in case the two compared elements are equal and the comparison to the previous element also returns equal. This way, only the first element of a run will return equal.

This is a little contrived, better implement your own search function.